# Image and text side by side in div, want to shrink image on resize

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a div with an image on the left and some text on the right. I'm using flexbox so that as the screen narrows the text pops below the image.

What I want to have happen on narrowing the screen is to have not only the text narrow but the image to shrink as well and maintain its position. Instead what is happening is the text shrinks and the image moves down the page (staying the same size) to maintain being centered. I suspect this has something to do with the `align-items: center` trying to maintain centering but I removed that then the image just stretches.

How can I resolve it?

```css
.bio {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  align-items: center;
}

.bio-text {
  flex: 200px;
}

.bio-text p {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: "Nunito sans", sans-serif;
}

.bio-h3-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.headshot {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div className="bio">
  <img className="headshot" src={Headshot} />
  <div className="bio-text">
    <div className="bio-h3-container">
      <h3>Bio</h3>
    </div>
    <p>...bunch of text here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the image a `background-image` by using inline styling i.e. `style={{backgroundImage: Headshot}}`

Then put the css class `background-size: contain` on it. This should make it so the image resizes to the div

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this and unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem of the image still moving down on the page as the screen narrows.

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet, have you tried setting the `justify-content` to `start`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
.bio {flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

to

```
.bio {flex-wrap: nowrap;}
```

You might also need to put the image in a div and define a width other than max at 100%

Comment: Unfortunately when I set it to nowrap the text doesn't go below the image on resize.